# Strange error while trying to attach email attachment in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtplib

I am trying to send an email using python. I am getting a strange error while I am trying to attach attachment to it.

I get an error when I try to pass an array value to attachment.add_header() function, but when I assign that value to a variable and try passing that variable then it works!. The strange part is that the variable and the array value have the same value

**Works(This code works perfectly)**

```
attachmentfile = attachment[0] # assign the array value to a variable and it workd
attachment = self.guess_and_get_attachment_type(attachmentfile)
# Set the filename parameter
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename = attachmentfile)
message.attach(attachment)
```

**Doesn’t work(Just remove the variable assignment and code gives error)**

```
attachment = self.guess_and_get_attachment_type(attachment[0])
# Set the filename parameter 
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename = attachment[0]
message.attach(attachment)
```

**Traceback**

```
 File "Email.py", line 224, in <module>
    main()
  File "Email.py", line 221, in main
    mail.send_email()
  File "Email.py", line 202, in send_email
    email = Email(self.from_address ,  self.to_address ,  self.subject ,   self.body ,self.email_server ,attachment)
  File "Email.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.attach_attachment()
  File "Email.py", line 62, in attach_attachment
    self.attachment.set_attachment_type(self.message)
  File "Email.py", line 134, in set_attachment_type
    attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename = attachment[0])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/message.py", line 391, in __getitem__
    return self.get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/email/message.py", line 468, in get
    name = name.lower()
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from [this link](http://dzone.com/snippets/send-email-attachments-python)

```
import smtplib
import os
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.Utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate
from email import Encoders
def send_mail(send_from, send_to, subject, text, files=[], server="localhost"):
assert type(send_to)==list
assert type(files)==list
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = send_from
msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg.attach( MIMEText(text) )
for f in files:
   part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
   part.set_payload( open(file,"rb").read() )
   Encoders.encode_base64(part)
   part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' %    os.path.basename(f))
   msg.attach(part)

  smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server)
  smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
  smtp.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to you reassigning `attachment` when you call `self.guess_and_get_attachment_type()`.

In the first example, `attachmentfile` is the original value of `attachment[0]`, and in the second example, `attachment[0]` is the result of the function call.